# Automatic swipe items (cards) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-design

I want to make something like in this picture

[image: swipeable items]

or this

[image: 2nd gid]

but I want to make it swipe automatically using Flutter

I don't know if there's a widget that can help me or any package that implement it.

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider
use this

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) package in pub.dev. It does the scrolling automatically

Answer (score 1):

Try below code Without any package scroll list left to right or vice-versa or you can used [`carousel_slider`](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) package or [`flutter_image_slideshow`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_slideshow) package or [`card_swiper`](https://pub.dev/packages/card_swiper)

```
 ListView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: 10,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          width: 200,
          height: 200,
          child: Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            ),
            elevation: 5,
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'Card $index',
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
```

Result -> [image]